# Is the "pursuit of happiness" mentioned in the U.S. Declaration of Independence really a right "endowed by the Creator"?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, politics-government, simchah-joy-happiness

Near the beginning of the U.S. Declaration of Independence, we have these words:

> that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness.

For purposes of this discussion, I will assume that the term "Creator" means "God" (Hashem, Aibishter, whatever term you prefer, but it's the same God we believe in.)

I think we all agree that life and liberty are correctly, unalienable rights that all humanity has. But can we truthfully say that the same would go for the pursuit of happiness? Does God want us to spend our time "pursuing happiness"? Isn't happiness a gift that God decides to randomly grant someone, regardless of "pursuit"? If so, how would that be an endowed right?

Comment: I don't think life and liberty are unalienable rights of all humanity. I, for instance, do not have liberty; I am a slave of God's. Furthermore, God has full control on when I live and die. For now I believe He wants me to live, but that may change.

Comment: @DoubleAA - That can be debated, too. Why don't you post that as a question?

Comment: Is this a question on Judaism or on Thomas-Jefferson-ism?

Comment: Meant to be on Judaism. I'm talking about if God (the Jewish God or Jefferson / Franklin's God - whichever you prefer), granted Jews the pursuit of happiness as an unalienable right. Would you prefer that I edit this into the question?

Comment: I don't know where this is sourced, but most people quote the Rambam as saying that the God of the Christians is (are?) not our God, while that of the Muslims is....hence your assumption that "_the term "Creator" means "God" (Hashem, Aibishter, whatever term you prefer, but it's the same God we believe in_" is untrue......doesn't mean that this isn't a good question, but I just wanted to point out one technical point

Comment: @Shokhet - technical point understood. I can't delve into a discussion of what the writers of the DOI thought, but I think at the time, use of the word "Creator" was a reference to God and not Jesus. Different point, maybe, if we talk about "In God we trust" on the U.S. currency.

Comment: It has been a long time since my High School history class, but I recall being taught that the phrase "the pursuit of happiness" referred to the ownership of property.

Comment: @shokhet  I think you raise a good point about Rambam's view on Avodah Zarah. I just want to clarify that there are many others who understand the trinity as different aspects of the divine. As such, Christians worship the G-d of Judaism and Islam.

Comment: Given my post above, I think it is reasonable to assume that our "founding fathers" declaration of the Creator's provision of "unalienable" rights refers to Hashem. However, in my opinion the declaration becomes less divine not due to doubting that Creator = Hashem but rather due to the obvious(?) fact that the fathers were hardly referring literally to all mankind. I seriously doubt that non-Whites were included in their paradigm, nor likely were women.

Comment: @JJLL Just to clarify: I understood the question to be asking about Judaism's view on the pursuit of happiness, from the viewpoint of the Jewish God....the background from the Declaration I just took to be a cute inspiration for the question

Comment: @shokhet. Gotcha. I am rather certain that Chasidesha believe/emphasize that one is obligated to pursue and experience joy and happiness. Their definition of happiness and enjoy are directly connected to Torah values and one's relationship to Hashem. It does not however  exclude earthly pleasures as it is believed that all physical objects clothe a G-dly spark within.

Comment: @JJLL I've heard that as well....source that and you have an answer!

Comment: Where's your source that the DOI actually says that? ;^P

Comment: @DoubleAA The DOI obviously does not govern God - its just attempting to govern the people under the US's rule.  It is stating that you have a right to liberty, freedom from slavery by a human master, and life, freedom from death by a purposeful human.  You can be God's slave and subject to His decisions about your life's continuity while maintaining life and liberty.

Comment: @LiquidMetal You are limiting the terms "right to life" and "right to liberty" without basis. Furthermore, I don't know why you think anyone has your limited version of those rights just because Thomas Jefferson[us](https://youtu.be/nIybz6axr1Q?t=96) said so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the beginning of the first chapter of [Mesillas Yesharim](http://hebrewbooks.org/51471) (see also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesillas_Yesharim)), [Ramchal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Chaim_Luzzatto) writes

> ויתאמת אצל האדם מה חובתו בעולמו....שהאדם לא נברא אלא להתענג על השם ולהנות מזיו שכינתו
>
> A person should realize what his purpose is in this world....that a person was not created except to have joy from Hashem, and to benefit from his Shechinah (Divine Presence)
>
> ~ [מסילת ישרים פרק א](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51471&st=&pgnum=34)

(*Translation mine*)

....**Is the pursuit of happiness an inalienable right?** Why, pursuit of [the right kind of] happiness is the whole point of our being here.

Comment: Emphasis on "the right kind".

Comment: Does that make it an inalienable right?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think anyone believes that God would deprive us of the ability to accomplish what He put us here for......or that any individual may deprive another of that ability......what do you think?

Comment: @Shokhet I think everyone needs to follow halacha.

Comment: @DoubleAA ......????

Comment: @Shokhet What is confusing?

Comment: You asked me if Ramchal would hold, based on the above, that the "pursuit of happiness" is an "inalienable right"; I answered that if this is our purpose in the world, it follows that it is wrong to deprive another of the ability to fulfill his purpose.....and you think "everyone needs to follow halacha" ....what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @Shokhet You asked me what I thought of your pronouncements about what God would do and what humans can do. I told you.

Answer (score 1):

In declaration of independence terms, "Inalienable right" means one that the human law cannot restrict (as in it would be wrong for it to do so) and "pursuit of happiness" [means](http://blog.dictionary.com/happiness/) the feeling of self-worth one gets from contribution to community.

So putting those in Halachic terms, an "Inalienable right" would be something that Dina DeMalchusa could not interfere with, and "pursuit of happiness" would be Osek B'Tzarchei Tzibbur.

So then the question would be does the Torah allow Dina DeMalchusa to interfere with Tzarchei Tzibbur.

At least for many aspects of Tzarchei Tzibbur it seems obvious that the Torah does not allow Dina DeMalchusa to interfere. It could not tell you to not give charity to the poor, not build a shul, not build a Mikvah, etc.

So at least for *some* pursuits of happiness the answer to your question is clearly yes.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link. I have to digest its message a bit further, in terms of how you integrated that definition into your answer. Nonetheless, that definition, I think raises some concerns that may challenge some of the recent Supreme Court decisions last week.

Answer (score 0):

In Mishlei 3:27 we have
אַל־תִּמְנַע־ט֥וֹב מִבְּעָלָ֑יו בִּהְי֨וֹת לְאֵ֖ל (ידיך) [יָדְךָ֣] לַעֲשֽׂוֹת׃
Do not withhold good from its owner while it is within your means.

The rights are about not interfering, they aren't (or weren't meant to be) about entitlement. I think אל תמנע applies well.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a right, but a commandment.

> תַּחַת אֲשֶׁר לֹא עָבַדְתָּ אֶת ה' אֱלֹקֶיךָ בְּשִׂמְחָה וּבְטוּב לֵבָב.
>
> ~ Devarim 28, 47

And this makes perfect sense. 
Like Aristotle writes on his ethics, a deed without happiness, lacks of meaning, because you are no doing it for the sake of the deed itself, and for the refinement that it's supposed to bring to your soul, rather, for some other worldly and time-limited desire.
So in other words, a life without meaning, is a life without acts of virtue and/or religion, acts that bring you closer to an intellectual/spiritual end your soul crave for. A life without good.

So the Torah (and maybe, in a related way), Aristotle and (again maybe, in a related way), the constitution want you to live a life with meaning.

Comment: I do not see a command in your quotation.

Comment: Is the constitution telling us how to worship G-d?

Comment: @msh210 not a commandment, and yet, it brings the most horrifying curses written in the Torah. How interesting.

Comment: @HaLeiVi Wearing tfilin is a way to worship god. The constitution is telling us how to live a worthy human life, and so does the Torah. (refer to my edits)

Comment: I agree with the other comments. This is not a commandment, but rather, a dictum on how to obey all the other commandments. It's a "philosophy" and attitude. Even if it were a commandment, there is nothing within these words that indicate a "pursuit" of happiness - whatever that concept may mean. If it were a commandment, it would not be an inalienable right, either. For all these reasons, I downvoted.

Comment: @DanF of course its not a commandment (or a dictum, whatever that means) is the outcome of doing Mitzvoth with the right intentions, for the sake of God. So you have 613 ways to pursuit happiness

Comment: It's not about the merit of being happy. It is about the fashion in which we are to do Mitzvos.

Comment: @HaLeiVi and why do you do Mitzvoth? do you actually think that God needs them? you do Mitzvoth for your own sake. To be close to God and reach happiness in this world and the next one

Comment: I don't do them for my own sake. But moreover, that is not your answer. You now seem to be bending towards @Shokhet's answer. You seem to imply that the fact that we have Mitzvos, which are for our benefit, proves that happiness is important. In that case you should rather quote ונתתי מטר ארצכם בעתו יורה ומלקוש.

Comment: @HaLeiVi "you should rather quote ונתתי מטר ארצכם בעתו יורה ומלקוש." Them I'm sorry, I overestimated you (all). I thought you were past the level where you translate happiness as material pleasures.

Comment: "The constitution is telling us how to live a worthy human life, and so does the Torah." I think you are overestimating the constitution as well.

Answer (score -2):

Being that the founding fathers were conscious of work ethics, 'mind your business' being an early motto, and considering their deep morals, i can't believe that their vision of happiness meant eating and drinking and the like. I would assume happiness meant more along the lines of what we call 'shalom' in the birchas kohanim. This shalom or peace or happiness whatever you choose to call it is granted to every human, however it is interrupted by other humans. The founding fathers wanted to establish a country of freedom, where every person lived his own life according to his own will without another person getting in the way. That was their theme whether concerning freedom of religion or capitalist ventures. While this is a true ideal, we know that true peace will only come from Hashem through moshiach or His brachah of shalom.

Comment: Peace and happiness are not equivalent. Peace may encourage happiness, but it's not a guarantee. Example - Israel and Egypt still have a "peace" agreement, for whatever that may be worth now. But are they "happy" with each other? I may have peace with my neighbor in that we don't fight. But I'm not too happy with him.